# another jsf <f:selectItems> itemValue and message bundle question

Tags: jsf, internationalization, el

i have a selectOneMenu with selectitems. 
if i use

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="#{hrBundle['phoneType3']}"/>
```

it works well, displaying the localized label. i have more options inside a List and when i use f:selectItems, it stops working. 
this code:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{values}" var="item" itemLabel="#{hrBundle[item.label]}" itemValue="item.value"/>
```

shows the key('phoneType3') as label, and even

```
<f:selectItems value="#{values}" var="item" itemLabel="#{hrBundle['phoneType3']}" itemValue="item.value"/>
```

('hardcoded' as the single f:selectItem above) displays the key ('phoneType3') instead of the localized label.

any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what the key in your bundle file is. If the key in your bundle ist the content of `item.value`, do the following:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.values}" 
 var="item" 
 itemLabel="#{hrBundle[item.value]}" 
 itemValue="#{item.value}"/>
```

I don't know, if this is your original code. If yes, notice the following:

1. You have to reference a backing bean
   in your `value` attribute (as shown
   above: replace `myBean` with your
   beans name).
2. The `itemValue` attribute needs an
   el expression as well: `itemValue=
   "#{item.value}"`

Comment: hi Matt, thanks for your answer, this code is in a custom facelet component and the `value` attribute is coming from a parameter, thats why there is no bean name.

Comment: my problem is that within the same `selectOneMenu` the `<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{bundle['phoneType3']}"/>` shows the label value correctly while `<f:selectItems value="#{values}" var="item" itemLabel="#{bundle['phoneType3']}" itemValue="1"/>` shows 'phoneType3'

Comment: I think it's because the itemLabel attribute in selectItems must refer to a _list_ of labels and not to a single label. So your `values` must be a list. Is it?

Comment: yes, it is. originally the itemLabel attribute is a list of labels too, but it did not work, therefore i decided to try it with a single hardcoded key. i keep trying, i am sure it should work the way you suggested above. i just make some small mistake somewhere...

Comment: ok, i was stupid. the problem was that my `value` attribute was a list of `SelectItems` and the `itemValue` and `itemLabel` attributes were ignored on the jsf page. thanks for the help Matt.

Comment: Do you mean if the value is a SelectItems list you can't get itemLabel and itemValue to work with it?